# How to filter rows in SQL statement with aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, sql-function

I created a [Total Calls Made] column within the SQL, and don't know how to access it. I'm trying to ONLY show rows where [Total Calls Made] is equal to 0, but since it's not really a part of the table, I can't just add a clause that says `where [Total Calls Made] = 0`. I attempted adding `having count(distinct f.[id])=0`, but all that does is make the non-0 values in Total Call Made turn to Null. Why is that?  What can I do to only select the 0 rows?

The SQL:

```
select 
    p.[ref] as [ID],
    p.[first] as [First],
    (select count(distinct f.[id]) 
     from [field] f 
     where (f.[related] = p.[id]) 
       and (f.[field] = 'person_that_called') 
     having count(distinct f.[id]) > 0) as [Total Calls Made]
from 
    [person] p
```

Results:

```
ID     First   Total Calls Made
--- |  ----  | ----------------
011 |  Bob   |       4
012 |  Susan |       2
013 |  Joe   |      Null
```

Desired Result:

```
ID     First   Total Calls Made
--- |  ----  | ----------------
013 |  Joe   |        0
```

Using a join makes all non-0 values NOT display, which is the opposite of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.[Ref] as [ID], p.[First] as [First], Count(f.[Field]) as CallsMade 
from [person] p 
left outer join [field] f on f.[Related] = p.[Ref] and f.[Field] = 'person_that_called'
group by p.[Ref], p.[First]
having Count(f.[Field]) =0
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Clean and straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cte

```
WITH    cte
      AS (SELECT    p.[ref] AS [ID]
                   ,p.[first] AS [First]
                   ,(SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT f.[id])
                            FROM    [field] f
                            WHERE   (f.[related] = p.[id])
                                    AND (f.[field] = 'person_that_called')
                            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT f.[id]) > 0
                           ) AS [Total Calls Made]
          FROM      [person] p
         )
SELECT  [ID]
       ,[First]
       ,ISNULL([Total Calls Made],0) as [Total Calls Made]
FROM    cte
WHERE   ISNULL(cte.[Total Calls Made],0) = 0
```

Comment: this will never return a result. In the cte, you are selecting rows with count > 0. In the query later, you are looking for 0 counts.

Comment: @vkp It should just return a `NULL` for that column `[Total Calls Made]`. and then the select from the cte will return the `NULL/0` rows. It'll still return an ID and First (like the `Results:` in the question show)